# Define the path data from code behind in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I have the following below path data which is in xaml. I want to define the same path data from the code behind.

```
<Path  Data="M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60 Z" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Codebehind :

```
Path orangePath = new Path();

        PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();

        pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(250, 40);

        LineSegment lineSegment1 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment1.Point = new Point(200, 20);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment1);

        LineSegment lineSegment2 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment2.Point = new Point(200, 60);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment2);

        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pathGeometry.Figures = new PathFigureCollection();

        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);

        orangePath.Data = pathGeometry;
```

**Edit :**

//we should have to set this true to draw the line from lineSegment2 to the start point

```
pathFigure.IsClosed = true;
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to use a `TypeConverter`:

```
Path path = new Path();
string sData = "M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60 Z";
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Geometry));
path.Data = (Geometry)converter.ConvertFrom(sData);
```

Comment: The question is about Silverlight, so this does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I've only done this with the Path as a DataTemplate as a listbox.  Should work.

```
//of course the string could be passed in to a constructor, just going short route.
public class PathData
{
   public string Path { get { return "M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60 Z"; } }
}

void foo()
{
   var path = new Path() { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) };
   var data = new PathData();
   var binding = new Binding("Path") { Source=data, Mode=BindingMode.OneWay };
   path.SetBinding(Path.DataProperty, binding);
}
```

Comment: and also `path.SetBinding(Path.DataProperty, new Binding() { Source = "M 250,40 L200,20 L200,60 Z" });`