# Setting Path.Data in code-behind

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have this XAML code which makes a `Path` which is inside a `Canvas` residing in a MainPage.xaml page.

```
<Path x:Name="progressPath" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stroke="Gold" StrokeThickness="5"
        Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300" Height="305" Width="305"
        Data="m 150,0 A 150,0 0 0 0 150,0 A 150,150 0 0 0 150,0">
    </Path>
```

I want to have several `Path`'s like this one (for example, a new `Path` is made when the user taps a button), so I decided to create them in the code-behind - which doesn't seem to be possible.

The `Path`'s  `Data` is populated with the [move and draw commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535793.aspx) syntax which cannot directly be used as a text value (as shown above) in code-behind like it can be in xaml - I've found [workarounds for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493163/define-the-path-data-from-code-behind-in-silverlight) in Silverlight and I tried the same technique in my Metro/Windows-Store app but though it compiles correctly there is no `Path` on the screen.

---

**tl;dr** How do I create this `Path` in code-behind with the `Data` being as shown ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this probelm too a while ago in winrt. It seems that you cannot asign a "path" value directly in code behind.

However there is a solution [here](https://stringtopathgeometry.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PathConverter/PathConverter/StringToPathGeometryConverter.cs)

I used this class in winrt without any problem. All I had to do is change the signatures of the Convert and ConvertBack methods to implement the IValueConverter interface as it is in winrt and not in silverlight.
Here they are

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string path = value as string;
        if (null != path)
            return Convert(path);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        PathGeometry geometry = value as PathGeometry;

        if (null != geometry)
            return ConvertBack(geometry);
        else
            return default(string);
    }
```

Usage: (More or less)

```
var stringToPathGeometryConverter = new StringToPathGeometryConverter();
string pathData = "m 150,0 A 150,0 0 0 0 150,0 A 150,150 0 0 0 150,0" ;
progressPath.Data = stringToPathGeometryConverter.Convert(pathData);
```

Comment: FYI the link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is to use *XamlReader* for this with apropriate string loaded. In C#6.0 it can look like this:

```
Path pathFromCode = XamlReader.Load($"<Path xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'><Path.Data>{stringPathData}</Path.Data></Path>") as Path;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an simpler alternative way to create a `Path` in code behind.

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Geometry));
string pathData = "m 150,0 A 150,0 0 0 0 150,0 A 150,150 0 0 0 150,0";
var path = new Path
{
    Data = (Geometry)converter.ConvertFrom(pathData),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
PathName.Data = Geometry.Parse("Path string here");
```

You can replace the string with other Path data as needed. For example:

```
MinBtnSymbol.Data = Geometry.Parse("M15.5 16 6.785 9.12c-.434-.343-.434-.897 0-1.24L15.5 1M1 16V1");
```

Then after clicking the button, it changes the Path Data:

[image: Clicking button]

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45710697/21987160) after hours of searching, since the other answers here are way too complex for something I only needed to do for one element.