# Is there an equivalent for WPF's Geometry.Data.GetFlattenedGeometry in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to find the `Point` that is *x%* along a `Path` geometry in UWP apps? In WPF this was possible using:

```
var path = new Path { Data = Geometry.Parse(svgLikePathString) };
var flattened = path.Data.GetFlattenedGeometry();

// e.g. x = 0.5 for 50% along the path
flattened.GetPointAtFractionLength(x, out Point point, out Point tangent);
```

---

**Context** I'm converting a WPF based application to UWP, where I can display different paths from the same array of points, a bit like this https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190. In UWP I can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880793/is-there-a-way-to-parse-a-vector-path-geometry-in-uwp-in-code-behind) to replace `Geometry.Parse(string)`, however `path.Data.GetFlattenedGeometry()` and `GetPointAtFractionLength()` no longer exist on `Geometry`.

Comment: UWP doesn't support `GetFlattenedGeometry()` and `GetPointAtFractionLength()`. You could think about converting your WPF application to UWP by [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) directly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes at this stage I have managed to get a working solution using SkiaSharp for the path operations. I think that will have to be my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Path inspection functionality has been removed on the UWP. I've managed to cobble together a solution using SkiaSharp (I also considered Win2D, however SkiaSharp supports more platforms).

In my path generating code, where I previously used the `GetFlattenedGeometry` I do the following:

```
// using SkiaSharp;

var path = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(mySvgLikePathString);
var measure = SKPathMeasure(path);    
var pathLength = measure.Length;

// get the position and tangent half way along the path
measure.GetPositionAndTangent(0.5 * pathLength, out SKPoint pos, out SKPoint tangent);

// do some magic to generate the SVG-like path in here and return the string representation
return GenerateSuperSpecialPath(path, pos, tangent);
```

Once I have the path string I can put it in my ViewModel and bind it in the template:

```
<Path Data={Binding MyPathString, Converter={StaticResource StringToGeometryConverter}} />
```

The converter looks like this:

```
public class StringToGeometryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var pathStr = "<Geometry xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" + (string)value + "</Geometry>";
        return (Geometry)XamlReader.Load(pathStr);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot convert from Geometry to string");
    }
}
```

Possibly not the most performant solution but it works and I don't notice any serious delays when drawing the paths.