# How to Convert WPF Path Data in C# Code (Geometry)

Tags: wpf, path, geometry

I think it is a easy Question for WPF experts but too hard for me, right now.

How do i convert this to C# Code:

```
<Path Fill="Red" Data="M150,300 L300,300 A150,150 0 0 0 256,194 z">
```

To Something like this:

```
Path p = new Path();
p.Data = Geometry...?
EllipseGeometry eg = new EllipseGeometry()
...?
```

Comment: try this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c48bb44-ff0c-4d87-a85b-8f07010fae6e/representing-xaml-paths-in-c?forum=wpf

Comment: `p.Data = Geometry.Parse("M150,300 L300,300 A150,150 0 0 0 256,194 z");` Otherwise, take a look at the online documentation of [PathGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx) or [StreamGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx). That's not too hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Path p = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
p.Fill = Brushes.Red;
p.Data = Geometry.Parse("M150,300 L300,300 A150,150 0 0 0 256,194 z");
```